# Count in string terms and stored mapped to other value

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which includes columns (amongst others) like this, with RATING being integers 0 to 5 and COMMENT is string:

```
RATING   COMMENT
1        some text
2        more text
3        other text
...      ...
```

I would now like to *mine* (for lack of better word ) the key words for a list of strings:

```
list = ['like', trust', 'etc etc etc']
```

and would like to iterate through the COMMENT and count the number of key words by rating to get a df out like so

```
KEYWORD     RATING     COUNT
like        1          202
like        2          325
like        3          0
like        4          967
like        5          534
...
trust       1          126
....
```

how can I achieve this?

I am beginner so would really appreciate your help (and the simpler and more understandable the better)

thank you

hi at the moment I have been iterating through manually,
ie

```
#DATA_df is the original data

word_list = ['word', 'words', 'words', 'more']
values = [0] * len(word_list)
tot_val=[values]*5
rating_table = pd.DataFrame(tot_val, columns=word_list)

for i in len(word_list):
    for g in len (DATA_df[COMMENT]):
            if i in DATA_df[COMMENT][g]:
                     rating_table[i][DATA_df[RATING]-1] +=1
```

this give a DF like so

```
   word  words  words  more
0     0      0      0     0
1     0      0      0     0
2     0      0      0     0
3     0      0      0     0
4     0      0      0     0
```

that I am then trying to add to.... it appears really clunky

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: hi at the moment I have been iterating through manually,

Comment: Actually, I was speaking about the code. Okay. Can you clarify the question? Do you want to create a column, that contain amount of words in COMMENT?

Comment: apologies I am struggling to make that readable will add to question

Comment: You have typos in the code. Please, get rid of them

Comment: You might consider using `from collections import Counter` package.

Comment: thank you for your help! - I have one more question - code below works but I would like to only count full words and I cannot seem to get str.count to work - please see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it, key points learnt are use group by to pre-select data based on the rating, this slices the data and it is possible to alternate through the groups. also use of str.lower() in combination with str.count() worked well.

I am thankful if more experienced programmers could show me a better solution, but at least this works.

```
rating = [1,2,3,4,5]
rategroup = tp_clean.groupby('Rating')

#print (rategroup.groups)

results_list =[]
for w in word_list:
    current = [w]
    for r  in rating:
        stargroup = rategroup.get_group(str(r))
        found = stargroup['Content'].str.lower().str.count(w)
        c = found.sum()
        current.append(c)
    results_list.append(current)

results_df = pd.DataFrame (results_list, columns=['Keyword','1 Star','2 Star','3 Star','4 Star','5 Star'])
```

The one thing I am still struggling with is how to use regex to make it look for full words. I believe \b is the right one but how do I put it into str.count function?